# Laravel: Ajax live search returns error 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I'm following a tutorial to implement live search feature in my laravel project using ajax and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mylh7H844Ro.

I'm following the tutorial and understand every stap he takes but I recieve an error 405 (Method not allowed).
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

My view:

```
<body class="relative min-h-screen">
    @include('partials.header')
    <main class="md:w-3/5  m-auto pb-20 space-y-10">
        <div class="p-2 mt-4 flex justify-center items-center">
            <p class="w-10/12">Welkom Admin. Op deze pagina kan je al onze gebruikers terugvinden en heb je beheer over hun geboortelijst.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-mid p-4 mb-8 flex flex-row justify-between items-center ">
            <h3 class=""><strong>Gebruikers</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="border-2 rounded-lg p-2">
        <div class="w-full bg-mid p-2" id="Table">
        </div>
    </main>
    @include('partials.footer')

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-+NqPlbbtM1QqiK8ZAo4Yrj2c4lNQoGv8P79DPtKzj++l5jnN39rHA/xsqn8zE9l0uSoxaCdrOgFs6yjyfbBxSg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-ldc1sPu1FZ8smgkgp+HwnYyVb1eRn2wEmKrDg1JqPEb02+Ei4kNzDIQ0Uwh0AJVLQFjJoWwG+764x70zy5Tv4A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    {{-- Script voor live searching --}}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
                const query = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"search",
                    type: "GET",
                    data:{'search': query},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('$Table').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/home', [AdminController::class, 'adminHome'])
    ->name('adminhome');

Route::get('/admin/home/search', [AdminController::class, 'search'])
    ->name('search');
```

My Controller:

```
public function search(Request $request) 
{

    $users = User::where('role', '=', 'user')->get();

    if($request->ajax()) {
        $data = $users->where('id', 'like', '%'.$request->match.'%')
            ->orwhere('name', 'like', '%'.$request->match. '%')
            ->orwhere('email', 'like', '%'.$request->match. '%')->get();

        $output = '';
    if (count($data) > 0) {
        
        $output = `
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Naam</th>
            <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>`;
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $output .=`
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">`.$row->id.`</th>
                    <td>`.$row->name.`</td>
                    <td>`.$row->email.`</td>
                </tr>
                `;
            }

        $output .= `
        </tbody>
        </table>`;   
        }
    } else {
        $output = 'Geen gebruikers voldoen aan uw zoekcriteria..';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            let url = "{{ route('search') }}"
            $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
                const query = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    data:{'search': query},
                    success: function(data){
                        $('$Table').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: When I try your code, it returns error 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)...